# SPARQL How to get the type of an individual

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I made this ontology:

```
SensorOntology:MedicalCabinet-01 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                                   SensorOntology:MedicalCabinetSensor ;
                          SensorOntology:hasId "57"^^xsd:int ;
                          SensorOntology:hasValue "0"^^xsd:int .
```

I am trying to write a query to get the type of **MedicalCabinet-01** which is **MedicalCabinetSensor** by given **id** number. However, I am printing **owl:NamedIndividual** and **SensorOntology:MedicalCabinetSensor**. Is it anyway I print just **SensorOntology:MedicalCabinetSensor**. This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?sensor ?sensorclass
       WHERE {?sensor :hasId  "100"^^xsd:int.
              ?sensor rdf:type ?sensorclass}
```

Comment: The query is correct and **must return 2 results** for the individual `SensorOntology:MedicalCabinet-01`- one with the class `SensorOntology:MedicalCabinetSensor` and one for `owl:NamedIndividual`. How do you run the query and process the resultset? Please show the code snippet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edit my question. Is it any way to just print the **SensorOntology:MedicalCabinetSensor**

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to ignore results, so it's not clear which one you want to use - especially since some are quite obvious. Here are two options:

1. As you tagged it with Jena, use Java and ignore resources whose URI matches `owl:NamedIndividual`.
2. Use a `FILTER` in SPARQL, i.e. add `FILTER(?sensorclass != owl:NamedIndividual)` to the graph pattern of the SPARQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are multiple ways. Here's another:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?sensor ?sensorclass
WHERE {?sensor :hasId  "100"^^xsd:int.
              ?sensor rdf:type ?sensorclass

FILTER ( strstarts(str(?sensorclass), "[sensor ontology URI]") )

}
```